# how to check in TCL if valid x display has been set

Tags: c++, tcl

In c++ code we can use the following code to check if valid x display has been set

```
if (!XOpenDisplay(NULL)) {
}
```

How to check in TCL if valid x display has been set. What is equivalent code for above code in TCL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method is to see if `package require Tk` fails. Alas, this can fail for other reasons too, but even so.

```
if {[catch {package require Tk} msg]} {
    puts stderr "No DISPLAY or PATH problem: $msg"
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: In case we are not using Tk , what is alternate solution in this case